# _gaq.push Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

Here is my piece of code in head.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-*******-*']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

And here is another piece of code:

```
<a href="tel:8976414707" class="order_btn order_btn_phone" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClickToCall', 'CallRequest', 'Mobile', false]);">Order by Phone</a>
```

So the thing is I have to work on already built website and this code part of code is not working. Google analytics is totally new part for me.

So can anyone help me to know this code works and what are the mistakes?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the web console? That code looks fine to me, so there must be something else on the page that's causing it to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your pageview should be working, however your event is incorrect - you're passing a boolean as the event value when a number is expected. If you want to pass nothing as an event value, you can use `undefined`. However, you could just pass the event category, action, and label, as the last argument (non-interaction) is, by default, `false`.

With `undefined`:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClickToCall', 'CallRequest', 'Mobile', undefined, false]);
```

Without event value and event non-interaction:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClickToCall', 'CallRequest', 'Mobile']);
```

More info [Event Tracking - Web Tracking (ga.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

Comment: as of 2019 Google recommend moving to the new analytics.js. To implement event tracking see here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events